# How to Smooth Gradient Estimates for Steepest Descent Optimization

Tags: filters, smoothing, optimization

In [steepest descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steepest_descent)
methods of minimizing a function $f(x), x \in \mathbb{R}^d$,
[image: zig-zag descent path from Wikipedia]

it's common to approximate the gradient by finite differences:
$\qquad\qquad \nabla f(x) \approx gradest( x; h ) \equiv
{ {f( x + h I ) \ - \ f(x)} \over h } $
then minimize along those directions:
$\qquad\qquad x_{k+1} \  \text{from min} \ f( x_k + \lambda \ gradest( x_k ) ) $

Can a signal-processing point of view suggest ways of smoothing $gradest()$ in this context ?
For example, one could view the "zig-zags" in the picture above as high frequencies in $gradest()$,
to be smoothed out over the last few ${x_k}$.
But that may be naive: 
can one model, then smooth, zig-zags through non-uniformaly spaced points in 5d or 10d ?

Comment: Add a fraction of the gradient approximation from the previous iteration, and look up Nesterov smoothing.

Comment: @Emre, do you know of any connection between Nesterov (smoothing | momentum) and filter theory ?

Comment: No, why? As it stands, the question concerns optimization theory.

Comment: @Emre, afaik (correct me), Nesterov is used to accelerate big gradient descent / SGD problems,
and is very sensitive to learning rates.
Has anyone used it on e.g. Rosenbrock ? (I've tried -- terrible.)

Answer (score 1):

In the Probabilistic settings we have many methods applied to the [Stochastic Gradient Descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) in order to decrease the variance of the Gradient Estimation (ADAM / RMS Prop / AdaDelta, etc...).

The nice thing is to utilize them in deterministic settings.
So for instance you can use Momentum which to Signal Processing guy will look just like applying IIR / AR filter on the Gradient.

There are also methods derived from the Convex Optimization world settings.
There is nothing prevents us using them in any setting besides there are no guarantees.
For instance you can use [FISTA Method](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/080716542) or [Nesterov Accelerated Gradient Descent](https://blogs.princeton.edu/imabandit/2013/04/01/acceleratedgradientdescent/).

More References:

- [Deniz Yuret's Homepage  - Alec Radford's animations for optimization algorithms](http://www.denizyuret.com/2015/03/alec-radfords-animations-for.html).
- [Sebastian Ruder - An overview of gradient descent optimization algorithms](https://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/).
- [Shao-An Lu - SGD > Adam?? Which One Is The Best Optimizer: Dogs-VS-Cats Toy Experiment](https://shaoanlu.wordpress.com/2017/05/29/sgd-all-which-one-is-the-best-optimizer-dogs-vs-cats-toy-experiment/).
- [FAST AI (Sylvain Gugger and Jeremy Howard) - AdamW and Super-convergence is now the fastest way to train neural nets](https://www.fast.ai/2018/07/02/adam-weight-decay/).

Comment: That's quite a grab bag of methods, mostly for high-dimensional stochastic problems. 
Have you run any of them on a 2d problem like the one in the plot,
or know of such on the web ? Thanks.

Comment: Why would they not work on 2D? They indeed work beautifully on 2D as 2D is the limit of what can be shown. Have a look at http://www.denizyuret.com/2015/03/alec-radfords-animations-for.html, http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/ and https://shaoanlu.wordpress.com/2017/05/29/sgd-all-which-one-is-the-best-optimizer-dogs-vs-cats-toy-experiment/.

Comment: Also a nice read about ADAM is http://www.fast.ai/2018/07/02/adam-weight-decay/.

Comment: I asked specifically about a "signal-processing point of view", in the hope of some insight / visualization. Do any of the papers you cite consider that ? (Feel free to improve the title / the question.)

Comment: I gave the point of view of those methods, you may think of it as variance reducing by weighted sum of gradients.

Comment: @denis, Could you please review my answer? If something missing let me know. Else, could you please mark it?